# Read a database MDF without SQL Server installed by an instance WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, local, mdf

I read several questions and answers , but I can not find an exact solution for my problem , so I open a question too.

We're doing a program that uses the DLL inside of another project I call A.
A then the project is evidence to a database mdf .

The software will be install on the tablet windows without administrator permissions , this means that I can do to install a LocalDB of ms sql .
So should read the database from a local folder (where I'll put the MDF through installshield ) without sql server installed .
I'd like to know if you can read the MDF without sql server from the solution , as well as the program that I'm going to throw .

The language used is C# , WPF project with MVVM pattern if it can be of help.

Thanks I hope I explained , altrimeti ask in the comments that are online .

Comment: If you can't install localdb or anything else sql-ish with `mdf` databases, then .. don't use it. Use `OleDB` and `mdb` or some other library, e.g. `SQLite`.

Comment: I don't think you can install LocalDb without a admin account